# Multiple Sum functions with different Scope on same query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which says that All students have to take 10 courses, in which 5 are mandatory and choose 3 from other 5. So basically has 2 groups. Now I need to calculate the sum of total Credits and also Sum of group Credits.

---

Table #1

```
      StudentID ProgID ProgName GroupID  GroupName  Course Complete_Courses_Alert Credits
          1         100  MS       501      Mandatory  12       Remaining           3  
          1         100  MS       501      Mandatory  13       Complete            3
          1         100  MS       501      Mandatory  14       Complete            3
          1         100  MS       501      Mandatory  15       Remaining           3
          1         100  MS       501      Mandatory  16       Complete            3
          1         100  MS       502      Elective   17       Complete            3
          1         100  MS       502      Elective   18       Complete            3
          1         100  MS       502      Elective   19       Remaining           3
          1         100  MS       502      Elective   20       Complete            3
          1         100  MS       502      Elective   21       Remaining           3
```

I want the output as

the above table but with 2 fields more added to it.

i.e. Sum of Completed Credits(Total Credits)
and Sum Complete Credits(By Group)

This is what I have done so far,
 I have created a view for calculating total credits and GrouptotalCredits and then joinin it on the main query. This way again i need to create another view to execute more functions on the query..

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
select *
  , StudentGroupCredits = sum(case when Complete_Courses_Alert = 'Complete' then Credits else 0 end) over (partition by StudentId, GroupName)
  , StudentTotalCredits = sum(case when Complete_Courses_Alert = 'Complete' then Credits else 0 end) over (partition by StudentId)
from Courses
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd819/2).

Check out [OVER Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) at Books Online for more information.

Comment: The above query adds all the credits as per group and as per program, but not for the courses that are completed.

Comment: I've updated the query to add only `Complete` rows to the two totals; is this better?

Comment: Thank a lot Ian. It works perfectly. trying to create a view to do this. Did you use materialized view anytime.if yes, Can you please tell me how it works. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! Sounds like you're looking for an Indexed View (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) in the SQL Server terminology. One of the limitations is you can't use a `SELECT` statement with `OVER` in an Indexed View, unfortunately. That said, I don't think a plain old view would be that bad in this case.